# Google Places API Address search

Tags: google-places-api

I The example given on [PlaceAutocomleteAddressSearch][1] is not working for me. 
I am getting 2 errors getting an Uncaught fc Tg error in the console
looks to be in line 97. error text is 
    throw _.gc(a+" is not a function");return function(){c.apply(d)}}; 
  [1]: 
the other error is cannot read property 'setBounds' of undefined.

I am using the exact same code as in the example so I don't get what is wrong.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem since I am checking this on localhost, geolocation is disabled as of march 2016, so the geolocate example will not work since the browser doesn't support navigator geolocation if the site is not using https.